# Export records from SQL Server 2005 express edition

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005

I have a little problem. My friend has a database with over 10 tables and each table has over 90-100 records.

I can't find a workaround to export the records (to put in a SQL file something like this: `INSERT INTO .... VALUES ...` for each existing records) from his tables to import in my database.

How to do that ?

I tried: right click on a table -> `Script Table as -> INSERT TO -> File ...`

but it only generate the `INSERT` statement.

There are a solution ? or this feature is only for commercial version ?

**UPDATE**

You can use BCP command with command prompt like this

For export: `bcp ADatabase.dbo.OneTable out d:\test\OneTable.bcp -c -Usa -Ppassword`
For import: `bcp ADatabase.dbo.OneTable in d:\test\OneTable.bcp -c -Usa -Ppassword`

these commands will create a BCP file which contains records for specified table. You can import using existing BCP file into another database

If you use remote database then:

```
bcp ADatabaseRemote.dbo.OneTableRemote out d:\test\OneTableRemote.bcp -Slocalhost/SQLExpress -Usa -Ppassword
```

Instead of `localhost/SQLExpress`, you can use `localhost` or other server name...

Comment: are you wanting to get a file to import to another database or just have the records exported to a flat file or excel or something like that?

Comment: Only records if is possible or table structure but with records...The middle of problem is how to export these records that they are many

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably the simplest way to do this would be to run a SELECT statement that outputs to a file.  Then you can import that data into your database.

For simple moves, I have also done a copy/paste manually.  Sometimes it is better to use Excel as a staging platform before pasting it into the new database.  You may need to create a temporary table in your new database that matches up exactly with the data you are pasting over.  For example, I usually don't put a PK on the temp table at first and make the PK field just an INT.  That way the copy will go smoother.

In the corporate world, you would use SSIS to move this data around.

Answer (score 0):

a couple of ways you could do this.  One,select everything from each table and save the results as a csv or delimited file (you can do this from sql management studio).  You can also script the tables as create and copy the scripts over to the new database, assuming it is a sql server also.   Then for import use the load infile statement.  You may have to google the syntax for sql server but I know this works in mysql and oracle.  haven't tried it in sql server yet.

```
LOAD DATA INFILE 'myfile' 
INTO TABLE stuff 
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' 
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
SET id = NULL;
```

Or if you are going to another sql server use the sql export import wizard.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms141209.aspx